# Number of strings from 39 characterst with given length

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations, combinations

Suppose that I have a **Characters Set** that has length of 39 total characters. The minimum string limit is **3** and the maximum limit of a string is **15**.
I just want to know how many possible outcomes it can make from 39 character set if repetition is allowed.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $39^k$ strings with $k$ characters.

Using the formula for the [sum of a geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula), we get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=3}^{15}39^k
&=39^3\sum_{k=0}^{12}39^k\\
&=39^3\frac{39^{13}-1}{39-1}\\[12pt]
&=753789555901957381797159
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Please elaborate me more why you used geometric series instead of permutation and combination ?

Comment: As is mentioned, there are $39^k$ strings with $k$ characters. That is, $39$ choices for the first character times $39$ choices for the second character times $39$ choices for the third character times .... $39$ choices for the $k^{\text{th}}$ character.